# Group Structure of Rational Points a Supersingular Elliptic Curve over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ with $p=2^a3^b-1$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I'm looking at [this Jao-De Feo-Plut paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/506.pdf) and [this expository paper by Craig Costello](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1321.pdf). Both claim that for a prime $p$ of the form $p=2^a3^b-1$, the entire $(p+1)$-torsion of a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. Costello seems to imply that this follows from the number of points on such a curve necessarily being equal to $(p+1)^2$ (and in general, for any prime $p$, the $(p-1)$ or $(p+1)$ torsion is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$), but I don't understand why even this claim is true. Can someone give me a couple pointers to understand what's behind either/both of these claims?

Edit: there's also a stipulation that $p\equiv 3\mod 4,$ so $p$ is actually of the form $p=2^{2a}3^b-1$.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of Frobenius at $p$ (as an endomorphism) on an elliptic curve $E/\mathbf{F}_p$ is $x^2 - a_p x + p$, and when $E$ is supersingular (and $p > 3$) then $a_p = 0$. So on $E[p+1]$, the characteristic polynomial (for $p > 3$) is given by $x^2 -1$. That implies that the square of Frobenius acts trivially and hence $E[p+1]$ is all defined over $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$.

Comment: @user814106 That looks like an answer to me! Would you care to record it as an answer below?

Comment: I thought that we had $p | a_p$, but not necessarily $a_p=0$? Also, let $\pi_p$ be the p-power frobenius endomorphism. Wouldn't the same line of reasoning imply that $\pi_p^2(P)=-P$ for every element in $E[p-1]$, meaning the $(p-1)$-torsion is never defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$?

Comment: In the case of $p >3$ we do have $a_p = 0$ whenever $p|a_p$ as the Hasse-Weil bound gives $|a_p |< 2\sqrt{p} < p$ for $p>3$.

Comment: Okay, so I'm convinced for the case that the curve is defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$. But what about the case where it's only defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$?

Comment: It's surely not true for a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$. Take the (restriction) of the original $E/\mathbf{F}_p$ to $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$ and $\phi_q$ (for $q = p^2$) has characteristic polynomial $(x-p)^2$. Now twist by an unramified quadratic character. so $\phi_q$ has characteristic polynomial $(x+p)^2$. Now $\phi_q$ acts by $-1$ on $E[p+1]$. Similarly, as in your comment, if $E$ is defined over $\mathbf{F}_p$, then $\phi_q$ also acts by $-1$, and so the only part of $E[p-1]$ that can be defined over $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$ is the $2$-torsion.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. Why does $\phi_q$ act by $-1$ on $E[p+1]$?

Comment: If $E'/k$ is the twist of $E/k$ by the unramified quadratic character of the finite field $k$ of order $q$, and $x^2 + a x + q$ is the char poly of $\phi_{E,k}$, then $x^2 - a x + q$ is the char poly of $\phi_{E',k}$, thus replacing $(x-p)^2 = x^2 - 2p x + p^2$ by $(x+p)^2 = x^2 + 2px + p^2$.

Comment: I'm not following, but I'm suspicious of your claim that it's never true for curves defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. For one, all curves defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ are defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. Secondly, I can use sage to show you an elliptic curve for which it is true. Consider the curve given by $y^2=x^3+i*x^2+x$ (where $i^2=-1$) over $\mathbb{F}_{11^2}$. $E(\mathbb{F}_{121})$ is isomorphic to $Z/12Z \times Z/12Z$. There are 144 12-torsion points... so in this case at least, the $(p+1)$-torsion is indeed defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.

Comment: I didn't say it is *never* true, which would be ridiculous since I  already *proved* it was true for elliptic curves coming from $\mathbf{F}_p$. I was just explaining why it was not *always true*.

Answer (score 1):

In SIDH, we work only with $j$-invariants. (The shared secret obtained by both parties at the end is a $j$-invariant.) Since we work only with $j$-invariants, all twists of an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ are conflated for this purpose. We always use the twist that has $(p+1)^2$ points.

Tate's isogeny theorem states that two elliptic curves $E$ and $E'$ are isogenous via an isogeny defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}$ if and only if the cardinality of $E(\mathbb{F})$ equals the cardinality of $E'(\mathbb{F})$. Since we start with a curve $E_0$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and consider only curves isogenous to $E_0$ via an isogeny defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, we always remain with curves of the same cardinality over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, namely curves with $(p+1)^2$ points.

Comment: What is critical here is that you start with $E_0$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$. A supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$ can have other characteristic polynomials of Frobenius, such as $x^2 - px + p$ when $p \not\equiv 1 \bmod 3$, and the claims of the OP are simply not true for such an $E$. (I assume you are careful in your paper and the OP misinterpreted the setup.)